# using grep for particular lines in text files

Tags: grep, text-processing

```
     2              METEOROLOGICAL DATA                         VERSION /      
     8    PR    TD    HR    ZW    ZT    WD    WS    RI      # / TYPES OF   MOD/TYPE/ACC 
  3979316.8350  1050313.7180  4857065.7030      592.1910 PR SENSOR POS XYZ/H           
                                                            END OF HEADER 
 10  1  1  0  0 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
 10  1  1  0  1 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
 10  1  1  0  2 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
 10  1  1  0 15 15  927.9    4.2   99.1               
 10  1  1  0 16 15  927.9    4.2   99.0                
 10  1  1  0 30 15  927.7    4.1   99.1                
 10  1  1  0 31 15  927.7    4.1   99.1                
 10  1  1  0 45 15  927.5    4.1   99.1                
 10  1  1  0 46 15  927.5    4.0   99.1                
 10  1  1  1  0 15  927.4    4.1   99.1                
 10  1  1  1  1 15  927.4    4.1   99.1
```

In this example of text data, how can I extract all 0,15,30,45 in 5th column of numeric data orderly, after the "`END OF HEADER`" part as follows;

```
10  1  1  0  0 15  927.9    4.3   99.1  
10  1  1  0 15 15  927.9    4.2   99.1 
10  1  1  0 30 15  927.7    4.1   99.1 
10  1  1  0 45 15  927.5    4.1   99.1
10  1  1  1  0 15  927.4    4.1   99.1
```

Comment: hrm.. I think I got a idea, it makes it a stupidly large string but you can pick out them numbers with print, lemme look

Comment: For structured (columnar) data it is often more straightforward to use `awk` or `perl` e.g. `awk 'NR > 4 && ($5 == 0 || $5 == 15 || $5 == 30 || $5 == 45)' data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `sed` and `awk`:
(assuming your subject text is in a file called `example.txt`)

```
sed -n '/END OF HEADER/,${
/END OF HEADER/d
p
}' example.txt | awk '($5 == 0 || $5 == 15 || $5 == 30 || $5 == 45)'
```

<sub>Attribution - the awk command was taken from steeldriver's comment</sub>

#### Explanation

Sed

- ignore everything up to `/END OF HEADER/`
- `/END OF HEADER/d` means delete the line containing `/END OF HEADER/` out of the pattern space, and because its no longer in the pattern space, the next command `p` won't do anything
- p - print each line as it gets pulled into the pattern space

Awk

- if column 5 is 0 or 15 or 30 or 45 then print it

Comment: If awk is on the table, you may as well do the end-of-header test there as well e.g. `awk '/END OF HEADER/ {body=1} body && ($5 == 0 || $5 == 15 || $5 == 30 || $5 == 45)'`

Comment: @steeldriver yes,  that is clearly a cleaner command, and - if you were to provide an explanation  of how it worked for the rest of us, it would be a better answer than mine. I gave the answer I did  just  because I'm familiar with `sed`  .

Comment: @the_velour_fog, how should I modify the codes to extract first 0 15 30 45 if these numbers in 5th column are repeats consecutively?.

Comment: @deepblue_86 you mean if you get 2 or more lines of output that are the same as each other? try piping output to `uniq`, i.e. add `| uniq` to the end of the command. `uniq` is a command to omit repeated lines

Answer (score 4):

A quick one liner would be:

```bsh
$ awk '$5 == '0' || $5 == '15' ||  $5 == '30' ||  $5 == '45' {print}' test.txt
```

As fedorqui mentioned in the comment below and even quicker one liner is:

```bsh
$ awk '$5 ~ /^(0|15|30|45)$/' test.txt
```

**Syntax explaned:**

```
$5  - the desired column from the text.
~   - the match symbol... matching was between the two slashes (/).
^/$ - the regex symbols indicating the beginning and end of the field.
|   - the or specifier for either item in the "()" group.
```

*The header is filtered out by only accepting lines that match the items following the match `~`  criteria.*

Comment: `print` is the default action in `awk` when something is True. So you can just drop it. Then, in fact you can say `awk '$5 ~ /^(0|15|30|45)$/'` file or play around with `!($5%15)`.

Comment: Great! I'll add it to the formatted answer above.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly do-able in `grep`, although `awk` is the go-to tool for field separated data.

With `grep`:

```
grep -E '^10[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}(0|15|30|45)[[:blank:]]' file.txt
```

- Matching `10` at the start, `([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}` matches the next 3 fields and then matching 5th field for the desired ones

If you use PCRE (`-P`), you can replace `[:blank:]` with `\s`, looks good on eyes:

```
grep -P '^10\s+([^\s]+\s+){3}(0|15|30|45)\s' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt                                        
    2              METEOROLOGICAL DATA                         VERSION /      
    8    PR    TD    HR    ZW    ZT    WD    WS    RI      # / TYPES OF   MOD/TYPE/ACC 
 3979316.8350  1050313.7180  4857065.7030      592.1910 PR SENSOR POS XYZ/H           
                                                           END OF HEADER 
10  1  1  0  0 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
10  1  1  0  1 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
10  1  1  0  2 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
10  1  1  0 15 15  927.9    4.2   99.1               
10  1  1  0 16 15  927.9    4.2   99.0                
10  1  1  0 30 15  927.7    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  0 31 15  927.7    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  0 45 15  927.5    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  0 46 15  927.5    4.0   99.1                
10  1  1  1  0 15  927.4    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  1  1 15  927.4    4.1   99.1    

$ grep -E '^10[[:blank:]]+([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}(0|15|30|45)[[:blank:]]' file.txt
10  1  1  0  0 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
10  1  1  0 15 15  927.9    4.2   99.1               
10  1  1  0 30 15  927.7    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  0 45 15  927.5    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  1  0 15  927.4    4.1   99.1                

$ grep -P '^10\s+([^\s]+\s+){3}(0|15|30|45)\s' file.txt                         
10  1  1  0  0 15  927.9    4.3   99.1                
10  1  1  0 15 15  927.9    4.2   99.1               
10  1  1  0 30 15  927.7    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  0 45 15  927.5    4.1   99.1                
10  1  1  1  0 15  927.4    4.1   99.1
```